# Reading from a text file in android

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to read a random line from a file. My code doesn't have error, just comes up with a force close as soon as it runs in the emulator and I can't work out why!

```
public class filereader extends Activity {
     TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lev1)); {

    try { 
        while (s.hasNext()) { 
            String word = s.next(); 
            t.setText(word); 
        } 
    } 
    finally { 
        s.close(); 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: check out android logcat, there should be an exception.

Answer (score 2):

> TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

you can not run findViewById until the `setContentView` has been called:

```
   TextView t = null;    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
}
```

please be sure that you declare `text` inside the `main.xml`

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
    BufferedReader myReader = null;
    try 
    {
        fIn = openFileInput("customer_number.txt");         
        myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String aDataRow = "";
    //String aBuffer = "";  
    try 
    {
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
            // TO display Whole Data of File
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),aBuffer,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }
        // To display Last Entered Number
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),last_number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for `printStackTrace()` then we might see whether *"My code doesn't have error"* is a correct statement!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readfromfile(){
    try {
         FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
         InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
         char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
         int charRead;

         while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
             // char to string conversion
             String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
             String s +=readstring;
         }
         InputRead.close();
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

It will read the text file named "mytext.txt" string by string and store it by appending it to string variable s. So the variable "s" contains final string taken from file.